# differentiable function with parameters

Tags: differential

I need to find the parametrs a1 and a2 so that the function is differantiable (derivable).I put the condition for it to be continuos and  down below is what i found.Im getting stuck however at the last part when finding the parameters,because I'll have -1=1 for a2.Am I putting the conditions wrong?[image]
[image]

Comment: More people will read your question and solution attempt if you write it out in English, rather than attaching photos of the problem and your work.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid explaining them in english as I'm from another country and the terms are different.

Comment: I understand that, but you're the one with the question, and you want to maximize the number of people who can answer it, right? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to deal with $f$ as a piecewise defined function can be a bit tedious.  You have to consider the cases that $a_1 < a_2$, $a_1 > a_2$, and $a_1 = a_2$.  Instead, think about what the sum rule for derivatives tells you.  If $g$ is differentiable at $a$, and $h$ is *not* differentiable at $a$, then $f = g+h$ is not differentiable at $a$.  Do you see why?  If $f$ were differentiable at $a$, then $h = f-g$ is the difference of two functions that are differentiable at $a$, so it would have to be differentiable at $a$, contradiction.

Apply that idea to this function.  Let $g(x) = x|x-a_1|$ and $h(x) = |x-a_2|$.  Then $g$ is differentiable for all $x\neq a_1$, but not at $a_1$, and $h$ is differentiable for all $x\neq a_2$, but not at $a_2$.  So if $a_1$ and $a_2$ are different, $f$ will not be differentiable at $a_1$ or $a_2$.  For instance, here is the graph of $f$ when $a_1 = -1$ and $a_2 = 1$.  You can see the two kinks at $a_1$ and $a_2$.

[image: graph of $f(x) = x|x+1| + |x-1|$]

If $a_1 = a_2$, then $f(x) = (x+1)|x-a_1|$.  The first factor is differentiable for all $x$, and the second for all $x\neq a_1$.  So we only need to check if $f'(a_1)$ exists.
$$
    f'(a_1) = \lim_{x\to a_1} \frac{(x+1)|x-a_1|}{x-a_1}
            = \lim_{x\to a_1} (x+1) \frac{|x-a_1|}{x-a_1}
$$
As $x$ approaches $a_1$ from above, the right factor is $+1$, and as $x$ approaches $a_1$ from below, the right factor is $-1$.  So
\begin{align*}
    \lim_{x\to a_1^+} (x+1) \frac{|x-a_1|}{x-a_1} &= a_1 + 1\\
    \lim_{x\to a_1^-} (x+1) \frac{|x-a_1|}{x-a_1} &= -(a_1 + 1)
\end{align*}
The function $f$ is differentiable at $a_1$ if and only if $a_1 + 1 = -(a_1 +1)$, or $a_1 = -1$.  Compare the graphs of $f$ when $a_1=a_2 = 1$ and $a_1=a_2 = -1$.  In the second case, there is a horizontal tangent line at $(-1,0)$.

[image: graph of $f(x) = x|x-1| + |x-1|$]
[image: graph of $f(x) = x|x+1| + |x+1|$]

Answer (score 2):

The function is always continuous.

Lets assume $a_1 \lt a_2$. The function:
$$
f(x)=x|x-a_1|+|x-a_2|=
 \begin{cases} 
      -x^2+(a_1-1)x+a_2 & x\in(-\infty,a_1] \\
      x^2-(a_1+1)x+a_2 & x\in(a_1,a_2] \\
      x^2-(a_1-1)x-a_2 & x\in(a_2,\infty) 
   \end{cases}
$$
has piecewise derivative:
$$
\frac{df}{dx}=
 \begin{cases} 
      -2x+a_1-1 & x\in(-\infty,a_1) \\
      2x-a_1-1 & x\in(a_1,a_2) \\
      2x-a_1+1 & x\in(a_2,\infty) 
   \end{cases}
$$

Lets assume $a_2 \lt a_1$. The function:
$$
f(x)=x|x-a_1|+|x-a_2|=
 \begin{cases} 
      -x^2+(a_1-1)x+a_2 & x\in(-\infty,a_2] \\
      -x^2+(a_1+1)x-a_2 & x\in(a_2,a_1] \\
      x^2-(a_1-1)x-a_2 & x\in(a_1,\infty) 
   \end{cases}
$$
has piecewise derivative:
$$
\frac{df}{dx}=
 \begin{cases} 
      -2x+a_1-1 & x\in(-\infty,a_2) \\
      -2x+a_1+1 & x\in(a_2,a_1) \\
      2x-a_1+1 & x\in(a_1,\infty) 
   \end{cases}
$$
In both cases, the function derivative is continuous iff:
$$
-a_1-1=a_1-1, \\  2a_2-a_1-1=2a_2-a_1+1
$$
From the first equation $a_1=0$. The second equation, never can be satisfied. Here no values of $a_1,a_2$ make the function derivable everywhere.

If both values are equal, the middle branch dissapears, and we only have:
$$
-a_1-1=2a_1-a_1+1
$$
which leads to the correct solution $a_1=a_2=-1$

$$
\blacksquare
$$

Comment: The function $f(x) = x|x| + |x|$ is not differentiable at 0, as you can see from a [graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x*%7Cx%7C+%2B+%7Cx%7C+from+x%3D-1+to+1). That's also not one of the options in the problem.

Comment: If $a_1 = a_2 = -1$, the function simplifies to $f(x) = (x+1)|x+1|$.  Just like $g(u) = u|u|$ is differentiable at $0$, so is $f$ at $-1$.